# php sql app not running in website but running in local host

Tags: php, localhost

I am running a app downloaded from github, the project is running very well on local host, but when i have uploaded in my website it is showing the erros as "Database Not Conncted".

However i followed the all steps on website as same as the required steps in phpadmin as in xamp server

i think the error is coming from "database.php" the fille with code to make connection, the database name is same but still the error.
here is the code-

[please see the code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7YdI.jpg)

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","quiz_new") or die('Database not connected');
?>
```

Kindly Help

Comment: Have you changed the database server address/IP? Some hosters don't use `localhost`. Furthermore, it is very unsafe to use the `root` user without a password in an online scenario.

Comment: Instead of saying Database Not Connected, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out **why** it's failing

Comment: The <sql> tag is for SQL language related questions. Replace with the tag for your dbms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move or publish a site to a hosting company you have to configure the database connection and sometimes the smtp server.

Verify:

1. You created the database on the hosting company
2. You created an user account with a password
3. You give access to that user to your database

Once you done this, please update your config files accordingly.

Never a hosting company is going to allow you to login as root on a mysql server unless you have a VM there.

Comment: can you pleasse elaborate step 3.

Comment: sure, when you create a user you have to give that user access to the database. There you can select what permissions you want to user to have. For example you can only give select and update and not insert and delete.